# Regex to also handle escaped delimiters?

Tags: javascript, regex

Say I have an input text cells of data delimited by colons, and I want to split that into matches based on runs of one or more colons, ignoring any initial leading colons.

Thus,

- `data_A:data_B:data_C:` is split into `data_A:`, `data_B:`, `data_C:`
- `:data_A:data_B:data_C:` is split into `data_A:`, `data_B:`, `data_C:`
- `::data_A:data_B:::data_C:` is split into `data_A:`, `data_B:::`, `data_C:`

A regex of `/[^:].*?(?::+|$)/g` appears to work. https://regex101.com/r/JuMZ65/1

However, I need to make this work where the colon character itself might be in a data cell, in which case it would be written as `\:`.

The above regex fails:

- `data_A::data_\:B:` is split into `data_A::`, `data_\:`, `B:`
- but the split wanted is `data_A::`, `data_\:B`

Additionally, the backslash itself could be escaped, like this

- `data_A::data_\:B:data_\\:C` should get split into `data_A::`, `data_\:B`, `data_\\:`, `C`

**What regex will work, handling `\:` and `\\:`?**

---

(My thinking process is not much more sophisticated than just throwing mud at the wall, so I'll spare you the mess of dozens of slight variations, half of which simply die on the table.)

Comment: Try `/(?:[^:\\]|\\.)+:*/g` (see [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/x9CeoT/1))

Comment: can you "clean up" the text first? for example remove trailing :, duplicate ::, etc?

Comment: Multiple colons have meaning, so cannot collapse them.

Comment: I can do simple clean up like ensuring there is always a colon at the end of the line, stripping off line-leading run of colons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
/(?:[^:\\]|\\.)+(?::+|$)/g
// If the match can have no trailing colons not at the end of string:
/(?:[^:\\]|\\.)+:*/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/x9CeoT/1). *Details*:

- `(?:[^:\\]|\\.)+` - one or more occurrences of

  - `[^:\\]` - any char other than `:` and `\`
  - `|` - or
  - `\\.` - an escaped char other than a line break char
- `(?::+|$)` - either one or more colons or end of string.

Comment: This is looking good. Running some tests.

Comment: One minor tweak: `(?:[^:\\]|\\.?)+(?::+|$)` .. this covers the case of the text ending with a lone backslah (which triggers a catastrophic backtrack)

Comment: @Erics I see, however, a single backslash at the end of string would render the string you have invalid, a backslash is an escaping char in your case, and to introduce a ``\`` you need to use ``\\`` in your strings.

Comment: Indeed it would be an invalid input. But users be using, and this is something we can handle.